# Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue when download large images

Tags: ios, objective-c

Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
I used sdwebimage after NSURLSessionDownloadTask but still facing issue

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: 8.2 MB image size and I used Iphone 6 for testing

Comment: when I test in iPhone 7 it's work fine

Comment: I would follow something like this: http://pulkitgoyal.in/resizing-high-resolution-images-on-ios-without-memory-issues/

Comment: You should use `ImageIO` framework to do the resizing first and then use it in smaller size to use in the app...

Comment: okay I will try this link - http://pulkitgoyal.in/resizing-high-resolution-images-on-ios-without-memory-issues/

Comment: Try and let me know if it worked